# Can i disable spring.cloud.sqs in testing environment?

Tags: spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I've created a simple project from https://start.spring.io with

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

with no edits tests fail for reason:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance.
```

I've tried to create src/test/resources/application.properties with

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

how is indicated in docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context
but the problem persist.

Anyone know how to disable spring cloud during tests?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with configuration class

```
@org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @MockBean
    StackResourceRegistry stackResourceRegistry;

}
```

and setting in src/test/resources/application.properties with

```
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
```